# Logical OR in SDL - field name 'OR' that is not defined for input object type

Tags: graphql, schema, graphql-js

I am trying to return students of who are either mature or highscool

```
graphqlOperation(listStudents, {
        filter: {
          type: { eq: 'student' },
          OR: [{ category: { eq: 'mature' },  { eq: 'highschool'  }]
        },

      })
    );
```

It looks like I need to add the logical OR in my schema

```
    input TableStudentFilterInput {
        ID: TableStringFilterInput
        type: TableStringFilterInput
        category: TableStringFilterInput
        name: TableStringFilterInput
    }
```

and my filter

```
input TableStringFilterInput {
    ne: String
    eq: String
    le: String
    lt: String
    ge: String
    gt: String
    contains: String
    notContains: String
    between: [String]
}
```

How  do I allow my schema to accept a logical operator?